# Changing class variable: good practice or not? (Python)

Tags: python, class, oop, class-variables

I have a class `Foo`, containing a class variable `size`.
I want to calculate the size the first time I create a `Foo` object and use the same for all subsequent objects, but not calculate the size again. For the sake of containing everything within the `Foo` class I came up with this code:

```
class Foo(object):
    size = -1
    def __init__(self,args):
        if Foo.size < 0:
            Foo.size = some_calculation(args)
```

In my small tests, it does what I want. However, is this considered good practice? Is there a better way to do it?

Comment: Could `Foo.size` ever calculate out to `< 0`?  If so, you may want to initialize as `None` and check `if Foo.size is None:`

Comment: Class variables certainly have their use, specifically for cases where data is shared across all instances... So, yes, if this does what you want and it fits the use case, it's fine.

Comment: Consider that if you do things this way, there may be times when you go diving for `Foo.size` elsewhere in your code before any objects have been initialized, and you will get an `AttributeError`. To avoid this problem, either use a `try` block, or initialize `Foo.size` as `None` or maybe `0` as part of the class definition.

Comment: Whoops! Never mind: looks like you are initializing as -1.  Didn't notice that.

Answer (score 1):

This is by no means an exhaustive answer, but I would like to point out something I cannot describe easily in a comment.

As said in the comments, there's nothing wrong with your approach.
It depends on what you want to do.

Let me point out that in case in the future you end up defining a subclass which calculates `size` according to a different rule/initial value, it may be useful to refer to it via `self.` (instead of reaching it via the class' name)

e.g.

```
>>> class A:
...  size=1
...  def printsize(self):
...   print(self.size)
... 
>>> class B(A):
...  size=2
... 
>>> a=B()
>>> a.printsize()
2
```